# 1 duplicate and 1 closed question - enough to limit my account from posting?

Tags: support

I had a novice account here, 4 questions asked (more answers):

https://serverfault.com/users/208540/t-todua?tab=questions

and out of 4, only 1 was marked as duplicate and 1 closed. However, my account is suspended from posting questions. Is that 2 questions that much to limit my account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The six deleted questions probably also have something to do with it.  But nobody -- not even the site moderators -- can see the exact reasons why an account is blocked from posting, so if you need an authoritative answer, your only recourse is to contact Stack Overflow staff.

Comment: ouch thanks. how i could see my deleted questions? I've checked and none was shown under my "deleted questions."

Answer (score 1):

Further to Womble's answer:

This is the definitive Q&A about question and answer bans:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

A few important points:

- You've been banned from asking questions, you can still post answers.
- There is no way for a moderator or for an SE staff member to un-ban you.  There's no point in trying to contact SE staff, the Q&A posted above contains all the information available.
- If you can improve some of your questions by editing them and if they then get some upvotes, you might be able to post questions again.
- The ban is not total - even when banned, you can ask one question every 6 months.  If you ask a question and it gets some upvotes, you might be able to post questions again.
- Only SE staff know the algorithm that determines if you're banned, but it's generally believed that your score on answers has an effect as well, so if you post some good answers that get upvotes, that might help.